# 'Use of uninitialized value' message on hash but I think the key exists

Tags: perl

I ran into something strange while debugging. `warn` is `print` by the way.

```perl
foreach my $key (keys %{$changeIdsRelevant})
{
    warn($key); # Icf4e037 is printed once
}
warn((keys %{$changeIdsRelevant})[0]); # Icf4e037 is printed
```

I wanted to know what value the key `Icf4e037` holds, so printed the following after the first block. As you can see I wasn't sure of the grammar and printed many..

```perl
warn($changeIdsRelevant->{'Icf4e037'});
warn($changeIdsRelevant->{Icf4e037});
warn($changeIdsRelevant{Icf4e037}); # this one 'gave requires explicit package name' error
```

The first 2, Instead of a value, they returned

```
Use of uninitialized value in warn at <file_path>
Warning: something's wrong at <file_path>
```

This `if` block also wasn't executed

```perl
if (defined $changeIdsRelevant->{'Icf4e037'}) {
   warn('============================================================');
};
```

Is it saying that the key `Icf4e037` exists but its value is undefined? But I feel like it can be said for every key in the world. Does anyone know why it still returned `Icf4e037` `keys <hash>`?

Comment: If you remove the arrow `->`, it becomes a different variable. E.g. `$foo->{bar}` is the scalar `my $foo`, whereas `$foo{bar}` is a hash `my %foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key can exist in the hash but its value can be [undef](http://p3rl.org/undef).

```perl
$h->{key} = undef;
warn $h->{key};  # Use of uninitialized value...
```

You can check the existence regardless of the value using [exists](http://p3rl.org/exists):

```perl
if (exists $h->{key}) {
    warn "key exists.";
    if (defined $h->{key}) {
        warn "Its value is defined.";
        if ($h->{key}) {
            warn "Its value is true.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another possibility is that the key is really `Icf4e037␊` or something.